# Is there a lint rule for python that automatically detects list +operator concatenation and suggests using spread

Tags: python, pylint, ruff

For me the following

```py
extras = ["extra0", "extra1"]
func_with_list_arg([
    "base0",
    "base1",
] + extras)
```

is nicer to read with a spread operator like the following

```py
extras = ["extra0", "extra1"]
func_with_list_arg([
    "base0",
    "base1",
    *extras,
])
```

Is there a lint rule in ruff or pylint that would detect this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is!

```py
c = [3]
b = [1, 2] + c
print(b)
```

When I run (my configured) ruff on this, I get:

> RUF005 [*] Consider `[1, 2, *c]` instead of concatenation

This is part of the ruff specific ruleset: https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/rules/#ruff-specific-rules-ruf and is a rule which is actually automatically fixable.